# How to handle short counts from write() and read() in Unix IO?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, networking, concurrency

I am writing a multi-threaded program with C. I want to send and receive data between the server and the clients using write and read function. I've tried something like this when I am writing data with its size - payload_size.

```
if(payload_size != 0 && data != NULL){
    ssize_t ret;
    int size = payload_size;
    while(size > 0){
            ret = write(fd, data, payload_size);
            size -= ret;
            data += ret;
    }
    // if(write(fd, data, payload_size) < payload_size) {
 //     debug(" payload write less than requested");
 //     //return -1;
 //     //write the bytes that have not yet been written
    // }
}
```

If the above works properly, I would like to use it on a struct I created. The struct have fields:

```
enter code heretypedef struct jeux_packet_header {
uint8_t type;          // Type of the packet
uint8_t id;            // Invitation ID
uint8_t role;          // Role of player in game
uint16_t size;                 // Payload size (zero if no payload)
uint32_t timestamp_sec;        // Seconds field of time packet was sent
uint32_t timestamp_nsec;       // Nanoseconds field of time packet was sent
} JEUX_PACKET_HEADER;
```

Is this approach proper to use?

```
JEUX_PACKET_HEADER *hdr;
ssize_t ret_size;
int size_temp = sizeof(JEUX_PACKET_HEADER);
while(size_temp > 0){
    ret_size = write(fd, hdr, sizeof(JEUX_PACKET_HEADER));
    size_temp -= ret_size;
    hdr += ret_size;
}
```

How does it work on the read() function?

```
read(fd, payload, hdr->size) < hdr->size);
```

How do I continue read from the fd when short counts happen?
Thank You!

Comment: You probably want to use the [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) system call (before `read` or `write`). Your question needs some [mre]. BTW, `JEUX` means `GAMES` in French. Consider using some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), perhaps with a library such as [libevent](https://libevent.org/) or [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/), and study for inspiration the source code of such libraries

Comment: You should read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and [sockets(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sockets.7.html)

Comment: In the loop with `ret = write(fd, data, payload_size);`, you repeatedly write with `payload_size`, but it is not adjusted to account for prior writes. The code adjusts `size`, with `size -= ret;`. You probably want `ret = write(fd, data, size);`. Also, test `ret` for a negative value, which indicates an error occurred. Similarly, `ret_size = write(fd, hdr, sizeof(JEUX_PACKET_HEADER));` needs `size_temp`, not `sizeof(JEUX_PACKET_HEADER)`.

Comment: Re “How do I continue read from the fd when short counts happen?”: Keep reading, the same you do with `write`? Why would this be different?